# Filter out posts based on a certain post_meta on the WordPress REST API

Tags: posts, rest-api, endpoints

So I'm going to explain this the best way possible, and see if someone might be able to help me out.

**Website 1** (*Posts located here*):

Let's say that our WordPress REST API endpoint is: https://example-1.com/wp-json/v2/posts

Since the native `v2/posts` endpoint doesn't support `post_meta`, I added support using the following:

```
add_filter('rest_post_query', function($args, $request) {
    $args += [
        'meta_key' => $request['meta_key'],
        'meta_value' => $request['meta_value'],
        'meta_query' => $request['meta_query'],
    ];

    return $args;
}, 99, 2);
```

Now, I am able to successfully query the REST API using the following endpoint: https://example-1.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=1&meta_key=original_id

I successfully get all posts that have a `original_id` as the `post_meta` over the WordPress REST API.

---

**Website 2** (*Pulling in posts from website #1*):

Now, on this website I want to pull in **ALL** posts **EXCEPT** posts that have the `post_meta` of `original_id`.

So I have the following code:

```
$response = wp_remote_get(
    https://example-1.com/wp-json/v2/posts?page=' . $page_number . '&meta_key=original_id'
);
```

This pulls in **ONLY** the posts with the `original_id` `post_meta`.

**Question**:
How would I be able to do the opposite of that `wp_remote_get` call? Pull in all posts except posts that have `original_id` as the `post_meta`.

Since I added `meta_query` support to the REST API, how would I be able to utilize that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that comes to my mind is to define your own custom routes for the API, allowing it to send results based on the route or use the same route with different GET params.

OR based on the way you're going with, you could probably send some GET params to the url and do things based on them by getting the params from `$request` and have conditions based on the params.

Something like:

```
add_filter('rest_post_query', function($args, $request) {
    $queryParams = $request->get_query_params();
    $want_meta = isset( $queryParams['want_the_meta_ones'] ) AND $queryParams['want_the_meta_ones'] == 'yes';
    if( $want_meta ){
        $args += [
            'meta_key' => $request['meta_key'],
            'meta_value' => $request['meta_value'],
            'meta_query' => $request['meta_query'],
        ];
    } else {
        $args += [
            'meta_key' => $request['meta_key'],
            'meta_compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ];
    }
    return $args;
}, 99, 2);
```

Mixed with:

```
$response = wp_remote_get(
    'https://example-1.com/wp-json/v2/posts?page=' . $page_number . '&meta_key=original_id&want_the_meta_ones=yes'
);
```

or:

```
$response = wp_remote_get(
    'https://example-1.com/wp-json/v2/posts?page=' . $page_number . '&meta_key=original_id&want_the_meta_ones=no'
);
```

Update 1:
if we want the original query to be untouched in case there is no specefic url param, this is how we do it:

```php
add_filter('rest_post_query', function($args, $request) {
    $queryParams = $request->get_query_params();
    $meta_action = isset( $queryParams['meta_action'] ) AND $queryParams['meta_action'];
    if( $meta_action ){
        if( $meta_action == 'include_meta' ){
            $args += [
                'meta_key' => $request['meta_key'],
                'meta_value' => $request['meta_value'],
                'meta_query' => $request['meta_query'],
            ];
        } elseif( $meta_action == 'exclude_meta' ) {
            $args += [
                'meta_key' => $request['meta_key'],
                'meta_compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ];
        }
    }
    return $args;
}, 99, 2);
```

this way if the param `meta_action` is not set to either `include_meta` or `exclude_meta`, the main query is untouched. I think `include_meta` and `exclude_meta` what they do is kind of self-explanatory. I also added some gaps in code and did it in the most basic way so you could get the idea and expand it based on your needs.
the call would look like this:

```
$response = wp_remote_get(
    'https://example-1.com/wp-json/v2/posts?page=' . $page_number . '&meta_key=original_id&meta_action=include_meta'
);
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Sadoo, I will attempt this method, is there a way that I can add a conditional so I have minimum impact on the native `wp-json/v2/posts` route, such that if I don't pass in a `meta_key` or `want_the_meta_ones` query strings in the route, that there is no impact on the original `wp-json/v2/posts` endpoint.

Comment: sure thing. if we don't change the `$args` we are not causing any changes. let me update the code for you.

Comment: Thanks so much @Sadoo, this works well! Looking forward to the updated code, thanks so much! I will upvote this post.

Comment: Updated it right there right then :)